# Jquery menu buttons set 1 default active color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a menu with 5 simple css buttons, but I need one of them to be default active. Here is what I have an is not working (without Jquery)

I need the HOME button to be active in another color by default. Any idea how to achieve that ?

```css
footer {
  margin: 69px auto 0;
  min-width: 374px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 69px;
  background: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  position: relative;
}

.botones {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 69px;
  line-height: 69px;
  background: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.botones:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.botones.active {
  background: rgb(255, 196, 84);
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="botones">About</div>
  <div class="botones">Team</div>
  <div class="botones">Home</div>
  <div class="botones">Wallet</div>
  <div class="botones">Support</div>
</footer>
```

Here is a Fiddle demo

https://jsfiddle.net/mb8xLp7z/

Comment: Put another class on the Home button and override the styling rules

Comment: Wow you are right, its a simple way but very good idea

Comment: Put active class on the home button

Answer (score 1):

Set active class to home

```css
footer {
  margin: 69px auto 0;
  min-width: 374px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 69px;
  background: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  position: relative;
}

.botones {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 69px;
  line-height: 69px;
  background: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.botones:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.botones.active {
  background: rgb(255, 196, 84);
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="active botones">About</div>
  <div class="botones">Team</div>
  <div class="botones">Home</div>
  <div class="botones">Wallet</div>
  <div class="botones">Support</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
footer {
  margin: 69px auto 0;
  min-width: 374px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 69px;
  background: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  position: relative;
}

.botones {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 69px;
  line-height: 69px;
  background: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.botones:hover, .botones.active:hover {
  background: rgb(180, 180, 180);
}

.botones.active {
  background: rgb(255, 196, 84);
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="botones">About</div>
  <div class="botones">Team</div>
  <div class="botones active">Home</div>
  <div class="botones">Wallet</div>
  <div class="botones">Support</div>
</footer>
```